# How to share dashboards among Google Analytics properties in the same account?

Tags: google-analytics

I created a custom report for one of my properties. I would have expected this dashboard appears for my other properties in the same account, but this dashboard  does not appear for my other properties. Why and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Dashboards are private to you until you share them. If you develop a Dashboard that you think is useful to other users in your account, or to other Google Analytics users in general, you have several options for sharing it.

You can share the Dashboard *template* with another property, although it won't have the data from the original property:

> The Share > Share template link option generates a URL you can copy
>   and send to other users, embed in a document or host on a website.
>
> When you share a Dashboard via a template, you share only the settings
>   for the Dashboard--you do not share any data.

If you want to see the data, you can schedule an email with the data attached (as PDF, CSV or more).

Source: [Share Dashboards](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1069386?hl=en)